# How do you configure Komodo diff using tortoiseHg and beyondcompare?

Tags: mercurial, diff, tortoisehg, komodo, beyondcompare

I'm trying to configure Komodo IDE so that it integrates with tortoiseHg and my beyondcompare3 diff tool. The diff works fine in tortoiseHg, but when I try to do a diff in Komodo nothing happens, no errors, no windows, nothing. Found a similar thread for SVN but need to know what to set the "diff options" box to for tortoiseHg (mercurial). thanks

http://community.activestate.com/forum/subversion-external-diff-tool

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the answer of [How to integrate FileMerge with Komodo 6 IDE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4249195/how-to-integrate-filemerge-with-komodo-6-ide)