# Using Beyond Compare 3 in Komodo IDE (6 or 7) as a Diff Program

Tags: php, tortoisesvn, komodo, beyondcompare3

I am trying to integrate [Beyond Compare 3](http://www.scootersoftware.com/) into Komodo IDE 7 as the diff program for Subversion.

I have BC3 working in TortoiseSVN as the diff program, but i cant figure out how to set it up in Komodo.

Komodo IDE is not listed in known setups for BC3

http://www.scootersoftware.com/support.php?zz=kb_vcs.php

I also checked the Activestate forums with no such luck

http://community.activestate.com/forum/subversion-external-diff-tool

I did try using the batch file method mentioned on the activestate forums as well as directly using the diff options in Komodo.  When using the Diff setting in Komodo with a direct link to BC3 i just get the current file im working on in a 3 windowed compare, I am aiming for a 2 window compare (subversion trunk and working copy).

The closest i got in Komodo was with the TortoiseSVN string from BC3s website but it gave me 3 windows, 2 of which had the same file name in them.  It also is adding the string "(Working Copy) to the end of my file during the compare and failing to load the file, if i manually remote this i get a comparison of 2 identical files.

This is the string I am using in the Komodo Preferences under Diff options

```
--diff-cmd "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Beyond Compare 3\\BComp.exe"  %base %mine /title1=%bname /title2=%yname /leftreadonly
```

I cant get anything to load in the batch file.

Comment: Use a [Run Command](http://docs.activestate.com/komodo/7.0/run.html#run_top) instead;  Click Tools=>Run Command, select "No Console" next to the Run In option, add the BCompare.exe location to the PATH environment variable, go to the TortoiseSVN document root using the "Browse" button, then run the application: BCompare.exe %F %f

Comment: I dont see a "No Console" option in the run command, are you referring to the arrow beside the Run: drop down in the Run Command pop up?

Comment: Sorry, you have to click the "More" button first. Then "No Console" is an option in the "Run In" dropdown that appears.

Comment: ah so this would be something i would have to run each time i want to do a compare?  I was looking more for a solution that i can set up Komodo so i can just press the Source Code Control buttons at the top menu and force it to use BC3.  Thanks though this did work

Comment: Good to know. It's not perfect but I'm glad it worked.

Comment: You can also click the "Add to Toolbox" checkbox in the Run Command menu to save it as a shortcut in the Toolbox on the right.

Answer (score 0):

Use a Run Command instead; Click Tools=>Run Command, select "No Console" next to the Run In option, add the `BCompare.exe` location to the PATH environment variable, go to the TortoiseSVN document root using the "Browse" button, then run the application: `BCompare.exe %F %f`

You can also click the "Add to Toolbox" checkbox in the Run Command menu to save it as a shortcut in the Toolbox on the right.

Answer (score 0):

### It works

> I am trying to integrate Beyond Compare 3 into Komodo IDE 7 as the diff program for Subversion.

I use Git and  Komodo 9, but I suggest for SVN and older version of Komodo this should works also (for version six please look at "[How to integrate FileMerge with Komodo 6 IDE?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4288753/3364871)").

Open menu "Edit > Preferences...", find "Source Code Control" and select your version control system. Check "Uses an external diff tool".

[image: Use external diff tool for Git]

Compare files:

[image: Run external diff utility]

and you will run Beyond Compare for your file:

[image: Beyond Compare compares file with its history]

### It doesn't work

> Use a Run Command instead; Click Tools=>Run Command, select "No Console" next to the Run In option, add the BCompare.exe location to the PATH environment variable, go to the TortoiseSVN document root using the "Browse" button, then run the application: BCompare.exe %F %f

I found that description in http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Komodo_Edit#Kdiff.2FBeyond_Compare.2FX-Winmerge_Usage also. But it don't work for me. And it shouldn't work, because it compares inappropriate files. Let's look what shortcuts mean (see "Interpolation Shortcuts" in internal help):

> %F    the full path and name of the current file
>
> %f    the basename of the current file

For instance, I ran Beyond Compare as described above for my current file and get value for these variables:

```
%F = D:\Projects\Languages\Perl\_music\Music.pm
%f = Music.pm
```

It doesn't compare file with repo's original.